# Export Highcharts as SVG from Java

Tags: java, node.js, http, charts, highcharts

What is the best way to get "Highcharts"-charts as SVG in Java?
My actual plan was to use hyjavacharts to create the "Highcharts"-charts as JS and then push them to an Highcharts Node.js Export Server.
Is there any more convenient way to create SVG files through hyjavacharts?
What would be the needed call to get an SVG file from my com.hyjavacharts.chart.Highchart object?

Comment: Highcharts is JavaScript library, so for chart rendering it's based on that. You could render charts using [node export server](https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/) to create charts server side, but there's no more official solutions expect this and [legacy, unadvised, exporting servers](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/258).